# Two wireless SSID with one DSL/Wireless router and another wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking

I know very little about networking, and thought I can read up on some of the basics however it still doesn't solve what I need to or want to accomplish.

I have a CenturyLink router DSL modem ZyXEL PK5001Z Modem - these are the speeds: 15.870/0.892 Mbps.

I've purchased a second wireless router TP-Link TL-WDR4300 and what I want to do is create two separate wireless networks in order to use one for Direct TV/Netflix/gaming traffic and the other for portable clients use. I've read on some posts that this is possible and tried to set it up as follows.

The CenturyLink router has most of the default settings, its IP address set to 192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0 \, radio channel set to 1. The TP Link router has the DHCP turned off and set its IP address to 192.168.0.2/255.255.255.0, it has different SSID. It is connected to CenturyLink router via network cable - at the CerturyLink router in port #1, and at the TP Link's router in "internet" port. Radio channel on TP Link router is se to 11.

I can see both networks but the TP Link's has a limited access, meaning no internet connection. So this is a question no 1, how to correct it?

Question 2, there are two frequencies on the TP Link device, 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz, which one do I need? or how do I determine what frequencies the clients use?

What also doesn't make sense to me is that CenturyLink router isn't set to a static IP addressing. So what's going to happen is the CenturyLink router serves out an 192.168.0.2 IP address which is the same as the  TP Link's address? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup you need to move the network cable going from the CenturyLink to your TP-Link off the "Internet" port on the TP-Link, and move it to one of the yellow LAN ports.

With DHCP off on your TP-link, you can connect, but with no DHCP the computers are not getting an IP address from the TP-Link.  If you had DHCP turned on, on the TP-Link you would get connected to the TP-Link, but you've have a NAT problem with your two routers both handing out 192.168.0.x addresses.  Basically the TP-Link clients would not know how to get out to the Internet.

Move the cable to a LAN/Ethernet port on the TP-Link and you should be set.

Different wireless devices can connect to either 2.4 or 5 wireless bands.  Keep them both up.  5ghz band is less susceptible to interference from cordless phones and such, but not all devices support it.

With your last question regarding the CenturyLink trying to hand out a 192.168.0.2 address (the address of your TP-Link), the CenturyLink will know what IP addresses are in use, and would assign a different one to a new device.

Hope that helps.